# calling executable with system command

Tags: c++, system, executable

I'm calling an executable from within  a c++ program via the system() command. Although each call is successful, I run into problems when the c++ code calls the executable many times while running. At that point, the executable takes a lot longer to run than it is supposed to.

I should add that the c++ code where the executable is called from is an optimisation routine. Yet, the executable is only called sequentially. After it finishes the c++ code continues to the next iteration and calls the executable once again with another set of parameters.

Are there any restrictions behind the system command that might be generating this? Is there a maximum number of times you can call it in a short time interval?

Thank you for your help.

MDR.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/) post?

Answer (score 0):

There is no restrictions behind system command, but you can have restrictions from OS. http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx

Answer (score 0):

system calls return immediately - when the command process is launched.  If you make multiple calls in short succession, you could be creating many instances of a process or shell command simultaneously.  This would consume memory and processor resources - thus causing the slowdown.

You want to know the time between system calls when you notice and issue and how long the process or command issued by the system call takes to complete.
if (time to complete > time between calls) then you will be creating multiple instances of the created process